# How to use prompt response in condition

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JavaScript and working on getting the hang of it.

I created some objects with a bunch of personal information properties. I was trying to make it so that when the website prompts the user ask for one of three names, when entering either name, to spit out where the person is from. Hope that makes sense. Here is the code. Remember a lot of this is just me practicing what I know. Some things may not seem like they should be there, but hey it is what it is.

So how can i fill my condition depending to the user response?

**JS :**

```
//Prompting who's information is needed//
prompt("Who's information do you need? Zack, Steve, or Bill's?");

//Objects here//
var Zack = {
    firstname: 'Zack', 
    lastname: 'Doe',
    address: {
        street: '5555 Timberwood Lane',
        city: 'Hotel',
        state: 'OH'
    }
};

var Steve = {
  firstname: 'Steve',
  lastname: 'Jobs',
  address: {
    street: '1234 Apple Way',
    city: 'Appledom',
    state: 'CA'
    }
};

var Bill = {
  firstname: 'Bill',
  lastname: 'Gates',
  address: {
    street: '5678 Microsoft Ave',
    city: 'Windows',
    state: 'FL'
  }
};

//Just a basic function, input name log Hi + name. Just practice. 
function greet(person){
    console.log('Hi ' + person.firstname);
}

//Functions used to retrieve information from objets Zack, Steve, Bill
function retrieveState(person) {
    console.log (person.firstname + ' is from ' + person.address.street);
}
function retrieveCityState(person) {
  console.log(' and resides in ' + person.address.city + ', ' + person.address.state);
}

//I want to make it so if I enter either, Zack, Bill, or Steve, into the prompt, it will print their information
if () {
  console.log(retrieveState(Zack) + retrieveCityState(Zack));
}
else if () {
  console.log(retrieveState(Steve) + retrieveCityState(Steve));
}
else if () {
  console.log(retrieveState(Bill) + retrieveCityState(Bill));
}
else {
  console.log("That person is unavailable!");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qmnpap2L/1/)**.

You have firstly to save the user response filled in the `prompt` into a variable :

```
var name = prompt("Who's information do you need? Zack, Steve, or Bill's?");
```

After that you can use this `name` to make your conditions.

```
if ( name == 'Zack' ) {
    console.log(retrieveState(Zack) + retrieveCityState(Zack));
}else if ( name == 'Bill' ) {
    .....
```

**FULL code :**

```
//Prompting who's information is needed//
var name = prompt("Who's information do you need? Zack, Steve, or Bill's?");

//Objects here//
var Zack = {
    firstname: 'Zack', 
    lastname: 'Doe',
    address: {
        street: '5555 Timberwood Lane',
        city: 'Hotel',
        state: 'OH'
    }
};

var Steve = {
  firstname: 'Steve',
  lastname: 'Jobs',
  address: {
    street: '1234 Apple Way',
    city: 'Appledom',
    state: 'CA'
    }
};

var Bill = {
  firstname: 'Bill',
  lastname: 'Gates',
  address: {
    street: '5678 Microsoft Ave',
    city: 'Windows',
    state: 'FL'
  }
};

//Just a basic function, input name log Hi + name. Just practice. 
function greet(person){
    console.log('Hi ' + person.firstname);
}

//Functions used to retrieve information from objets Zack, Steve, Bill
function retrieveState(person) {
    console.log (person.firstname + ' is from ' + person.address.street);
}
function retrieveCityState(person) {
  console.log(' and resides in ' + person.address.city + ', ' + person.address.state);
}

//I want to make it so if I enter either, Zack, Bill, or Steve, into the prompt, it will print their information
if ( name == 'Zack') {
  console.log(retrieveState(Zack) + retrieveCityState(Zack));
}
else if ( name == 'Steve') {
  console.log(retrieveState(Steve) + retrieveCityState(Steve));
}
else if ( name == 'Bill') {
  console.log(retrieveState(Bill) + retrieveCityState(Bill));
}
else {
  console.log("That person is unavailable!");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Save the response into a variable as the other answer states.

Then you can make then call a function to find the answer.

```
var name = prompt("who's information do you need? Zack,Steve, or Bill's)

function logAddress(person){

    switch(person){
        case 'Zack':
          console.log(retrieveState(Zack) +  retrieveCityState(Zack));
          break;
        case 'Steve':
        console.log(retrieveState(Steve) + retrieveCityState(Steve));   
          break;
        case 'Bill':
        console.log(retrieveState(Bill) + retrieveCityState(Bill));
          break;
        Default:
        console.log('sorry person not found');

    }
}

logAddress(name);
```

hope that helps